# Godot one player control two character first character forward not work

Tags: godot, gdscript

This is a game one player can control two characters，left hand control left character and right hand control right character，When I set project inputmap use W,A,S,D control left character, use left, right, top, bottom arrow control right character, there exist a situation that left W button not working：

Like player1 code is：

```
func _process() -> void:
    ...

    dir.x = Input.get_action_strength("left_move_right")-Input.get_action_strength("left_move_left")

    dir.z = Input.get_action_strength("left_move_back") - Input.get_action_strength("left_move_forward")

    ...
```

player2 code is：

```
func _process() -> void:
    ...

    dir.x = Input.get_action_strength("right_move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("right_move_left")

    dir.z = Input.get_action_strength("right_move_back") - Input.get_action_strength("right_move_forward")

    ...
```

When I first press right forward button，left forward button W not working。

Comment: You might be running into the maximum number of keys your keyboard can report.

Answer (score 0):

This is just keyboard ghosting